# MPMOVIEPLAYER when playing a video multple times in Landscape causes video to shift down and navigation bar disappears

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayer

I am writing an application that has imbedded videos. If I start the application in Landscape mode first and then start the video it looks good. So then I click on Done and then play the video a second time. The second time the video is now shifted down and to the left. When I click on the video the Done button does not show up. I have to switch the simulator to Portrait mode and then back to Landscape mode and then I can click on Done to stop the video. If I always start the video in Portrait mode, and then turn the simulator to landscape it will work. I can do this many times and the video will always line up properly. However if I play the application always in landscape mode, the video will always shift down and to the left for every play after the first time. I went through many of the other mpmovieplayer questions and compared my code to the other code. I am using IOS6 and Storyboard. I have copied my basic MPMOVIEPLAYER code below. I am really stuck here

MoviePlayerViewController.m

```
- (void) readyPlayer
 mp =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

// For 3.2 devices and above
if ([mp respondsToSelector:@selector(loadState)]) 
{
    // Set movie player layout
    [mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
    [mp setFullscreen:YES];


    // May help to reduce latency
    [mp prepareToPlay];

    // Register that the load state changed (movie is ready)
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                               object:nil];
}  

// Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing. 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                           object:nil];
// Register to receive a notification when the movie has exit fullscreen mode.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification
                                           object:nil];
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * For 3.2 and 4.x devices
 *  
*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
- (void) moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:(NSNotification*)notification 
{
// Unless state is unknown, start playback
if ([mp loadState] != MPMovieLoadStateUnknown)
{
    // Remove observer
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
     object:nil];

    // When tapping movie, status bar will appear, it shows up
    // in portrait mode by default. Set orientation to   `landscape`                                                                                                                    

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        // Rotate the view for landscape playback
        [[self view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
        [[self view] setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 240)];
        [[self view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)]; 

        // Set frame of movie player
        [[mp view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
    } else {
            // Rotate the view for landscape playback
            [[self view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 748)];
            [[self view] setCenter:CGPointMake(374, 512)];
            [[self view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)]; 

            // Set frame of movie player
            [[mp view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 748.0)];
        }



        // Add movie player as subview
        [[self view] addSubview:[mp view]];   

        // Play the movie
        [mp play];
    }
}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    // Remove observer
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification
     object:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: This is what I have learned so far. If I always launch the MPMovieplayer from a VC in portrait mode it always works in both IOS 5 and IOS 6. However, if I launch the MPMovieplayer from the VC already being in landscape mode it will only play correctly once. All following launches the video play is not centered properly. In IOS 5, it will play properly all the time whether the VC is in Portrait or Landscape mode.

Comment: it turned out that my code that shifts to Landscape should have first checked to see if I was already in landscape mode. Shifting to landscape mode when already in landscape mode caused it to be offset